# Azure Cognitive Services Intent Recognition: System.AccessViolationException

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, access-violation, azure-language-understanding

I'm currently working on an Azure Cognitive Services tutorial, specifically the Intent Recognition sample. I'm encountering a `System.AccessViolationException` when I use the `ApplyLanguageModels()` method from `IntentRecognizer` on my `ConversationalLanguageUnderstandingModel`.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```cs
var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(_speechKey, _speechRegion);
speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();

// Creates an intent recognizer in the specified language using microphone as audio input.
using (var intentRecognizer = new IntentRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig))
{
    var cluModel = new ConversationalLanguageUnderstandingModel(
                                                                    _languageKey,
                                                                    _languageEndpoint,
                                                                    _cluProjectName,
                                                                    _cluDeploymentName);
    var collection = new LanguageUnderstandingModelCollection();
    collection.Add(cluModel);
    intentRecognizer.ApplyLanguageModels(collection);
```

The error occurs at `intentRecgonizer.ApplyLanguageModels(collection)` and the stack trace shows:

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Repeat 2 times:
--------------------------------
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.Recognizer.intent_recognizer_add_conversational_language_understanding_model(Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.InteropSafeHandle, Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.Utf8StringHandle, Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.Utf8StringHandle, Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.Utf8StringHandle, Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.Utf8StringHandle)
--------------------------------
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Intent.IntentRecognizer.ApplyLanguageModels(Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Intent.LanguageUnderstandingModelCollection)
   at IntentRecgonition+<DoWork>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at IntentRecgonition.DoWork()
   at Program+<Main>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at Program.Main(System.String[])
   at Program.<Main>(System.String[])
```

I'm using Azure Cognitive Services SDK version 1.28.0. (VS 2022 .NET 6 Console App)

I've checked my keys, endpoints, and deployment names and they all seem to be correct. I've also tried updating my SDK to the latest version. However, none of these attempts have resolved the issue.

Does anyone have any insights or solutions for this `System.AccessViolationException`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart VS as I just added the environment variables needed.